# Components import error - Vue 2 with TypeScript - VS Code

Tags: typescript, webpack, vuejs2, vue-options-api

has anyone had problems with TS pointing errors on custom components beeing imported to the .vue file - using the options api and webpack.
Basicly the import works fine, everything is visible and working after bundling but still... i'm getting an annoying errors in the .vue template when using imported components
For example - VS Code displays an error "Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'" for components with no properties passed inside.
If the component has some properties - the properties are listed in the error like "Argument of type '{class: string}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'"

Anyone?
Thanks :)

I've already tried reconfiguring the tsconfig - no luck,
I've added the shim files - no luck,
Already tried the newest typescipt package - no luck,
Already tried splitting the component for separate .vue and .ts files - no luck,
I'm not sure but it seems like a IDE config problem?

[image]

Comment: Your screenshot does not show whether you determined that `PrintDialog` component can be used in your template. Have you added `components: { PrintDialog },` under `Vue.extend({ ....` just like how you added props?

Answer (score 0):

How did you specify the properties inside the `print-dialog` component?
This problem might occur because that component specifies properties that are required.

Could you could please show the code for that component?